# How do determine when DataSource is no longer used

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-datasource

I have a page with a Kendo Grid. When the user selects a row in the Grid I update a template and another grid with dependent information. I'm doing this by creating two new DataSources and binding them (see the code below).

To support live updates I want to attach, in the init() of the DataSource, an event handler to a websocket to detect changes in the backend for this DataSource (basically a subscription model). My problem is that in this page since every time the user selects an item I would get two more DataSources and so I would end up with lots of event handlers triggering for DataSources that are no longer used. I would like to clean them up somehow.

I can see a number of ways to handle this:

- Have some event that triggers when the DataSource is no longer used so I can unregister the handler and unsubscribe.
- Instead of creating a new DataSource each time just change the url in the transport each time. But then I'd like some event that triggers when the transport is changed so the event handler knows the subscription needs to be changed.
- What I currently do: add a custom method to the DataSource called nuke() which I call just before creating the new DataSource. Error prone, but functional.

Or am I going about this completely the wrong way? Perhaps there is some general way to trigger on changes in Kendo objects?

Below is code that demonstrates the naive approach that causes the problem. It's also available here: http://dojo.telerik.com/OKaDu

Note the example code uses filters but in my actual code it's the URL that changes. Though if there is a way to trigger on changing filters that would be cool too.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Kendo UI Snippet</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.2.624/styles/kendo.common.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.2.624/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.2.624/styles/kendo.default.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.2.624/styles/kendo.dataviz.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.2.624/styles/kendo.dataviz.default.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.2.624/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.2.624/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="grid"></div>
    <div id="detail">
      Employee ID: <span data-bind="text: EmployeeID"></span><br>
      FirstName: <span data-bind="text: FirstName"></span><br>
      LastName: <span data-bind="text: LastName"></span><br>
    </div>
    <div id="orders"></div>
    <script>
      var element = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: {
          type: "odata",
          transport: {
            read: "http://demos.kendoui.com/service/Northwind.svc/Employees"
          },
          pageSize: 6,
          serverPaging: true,
          serverSorting: true
        },
        height: 450,
        selectable: "row",
        sortable: true,
        pageable: true,
        columns: [
          {
            field: "FirstName",
            title: "First Name"
          },
          {
            field: "LastName",
            title: "Last Name"
          },
          {
            field: "Country"
          },
          {
            field: "City"
          },
          {
            field: "Title"
          }
        ],
        change: function(e) {
          var selectedRows = this.select();
          var dataItem = this.dataItem(selectedRows[0]);

          var remoteDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            type: "odata",
            transport: {
              read: "http://demos.kendoui.com/service/Northwind.svc/Employees"
            },
            serverPaging: true,
            serverSorting: true,
            serverFiltering: true,
            pageSize:6,
            filter: { field: "EmployeeID", operator: "eq", value: dataItem.EmployeeID }
          });
          remoteDataSource.fetch(function(){
            kendo.bind("#detail", remoteDataSource.view()[0]);
          });
          $("#orders").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: {
              type: "odata",
              transport: {
                read: "http://demos.kendoui.com/service/Northwind.svc/Orders"
              },
              serverPaging: true,
              serverSorting: true,
              serverFiltering: true,
              pageSize:6,
              filter: { field: "EmployeeID", operator: "eq", value: dataItem.EmployeeID }
            },
            scrollable: false,
            sortable: true,
            pageable: true,
            columns: [
              { field: "OrderID", width: 70 },
              { field: "ShipCountry", title:"Ship Country", width: 100 },
              { field: "ShipAddress", title:"Ship Address" },
              { field: "ShipName", title: "Ship Name", width: 200 }
            ]
          });
        }
      });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  Kendo API lets you hook up push events but I cannot find anyway to get notified when it is safe to "unhook" the push events.